# Getting a specific parameter from a Constructor Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a simple game using cards from a deck of cards as points. So far, I have created the deck of cards and printed it successfully. The program consists of 2 classes, **Game** (which holds the main method) and **Card** (which creates the cards). I am trying to make a method (the method is called **Points**) that returns the total of each card's number, but I don't know how to extract the card's value from the rest of the object. Is there some kind of deck.something to extract that specific parameter?

If this question has already been answered, it would be greatly appreciated if you could point me to that question instead.

Below is a shortned version of my work.

Card.java

```
class Card {
  private final String name;
  private final Integer value;

  Card (String name, int value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getName () { return name; }
  public String getValue () { return value; }

  public String toString() { return (this.name + " = " + this.value); }
}
```

Game.java

```
public class Game {
  public static void createDeck (ArrayList<Card> deck) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) { //creates cards 0 - 10
      Card obj = new Card("Card", i);
      deck.add(obj);
    }

  public static Int Points (ArrayList<Card> deck) {} //should return 81 = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ...

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    createDeck(deck);
    Points(deck);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one issue in the Card class. The return type of getValue should be Integer and not String

```
public String getValue () { return value; }
```

should be

```
public Integer getValue () { return value; }
```

This is how you can write the points method:

```
public static Integer points (ArrayList<Card> deck) {
        Integer total =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < deck.size();i++) { 
          total+=deck.get(i).getValue();
        }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class Card{
    private Integer value;
    private String name;
    
    public Card(Integer value, String name) {
        this.value = value;
        this.name = name;
    }

    Integer getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

public static int points(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
    return cards.stream().mapToInt(c -> c.getValue()).sum();
}
```